# show input if another control has focus

Tags: angularjs

I have two input text boxes in a form. The second text box is hidden by default.

I need to show the second text box if either of these are true:

1) the first text box has focus
2) the second text box has focus

I tried using ng-focus and ng-blur but I'm having trouble with keeping the second input showing if the second text box has focus and then I moved back to the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following will work.

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.inputFocus = function() {
    $scope.inputFocused = true;
  }
  $scope.inputBlur = function() {
    $scope.inputFocused = false;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input ng-model="input1" ng-blur="inputBlur()" placeholder="input1" ng-focus="inputFocus()" />
  <input ng-model="input2" placeholder="input2" ng-show="inputFocused" ng-focus="inputFocus()" ng-blur="inputBlur()"/>
  
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: you're right...this does work. I'm using the ionic framework and something seems to be causing it to not work there, but it works in a normal angular app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you set on having a JavaScript solution only? This can be accomplished in pure CSS using the following:

```css
input[type="text"] {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  display: inlne-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#input2 {
  margin-left: 25px;
  display: none;
}
#input1:focus + #input2,
#input2:focus {
  display: inline-block;  
}
#input2:valid {
  display: inline-block;  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Input 1..." value="" />
  <input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="Input 2..." value="" required />
</div>
```

I understand you're using AngularJS, but you may not need to for the showing/hiding effect. It may prove to be more complicated than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

We can use simple code like the below one. Where we have used `ng-blur` and `ng-focus` directives to change the value of the variable `$scope.showInput2`. Which manages the display of `inputB` using `ng-show` directive.

```js
angular.module("testApp", []).controller("testCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.showInput2 = false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="testApp">
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <input ng-model="inputA" ng-blur="showInput2 = false" ng-focus="showInput2 = true" placeholder="input A"/>
  <input ng-model="inputB" placeholder="input B" ng-show="showInput2"/>
  
</div>

</html>
```